# Highcharts Second yAxis wont scale to percent

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I setup a chart: https://jsfiddle.net/hanoncs/t6rkbp1L/3/ and the second yAxis wont scale to percent. Based on what im googling I should be able to do it this way.

I added the `alignTicks:false` and it doesn't seem to working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add correct y axis index in time serie description

```
name: 'OT Percent',
yAxis: 1,
...
```

Current implementation makes Highcharts assume your second timeserie is still in dollars

You can see more about multiple axes [here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes)